# Can I have classes with same name in one Java project in Eclipse IDE?

Tags: java, eclipse

I wanted to have two classes with same name in one Java project while creating project in Eclipse. Could anyone suggest how I can achieve it?

Thank you.

Comment: That's not a good idea, but just put them in separate packages.

Comment: Thank you for the replies guys. But, I do have classes with same name in different packages within same source folder. Does keeping two packages with same named class within same source folder an issue?

Answer (score 2):

You can do that using different packages.
It doesn't make sense for many reasons tho.

More: [Bad practice to have two classes of the same name in different packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6647510/bad-practice-to-have-two-classes-of-the-same-name-in-different-packages)

Answer (score 0):

Either rename one of the packages, or create a new workspace.