# Java naming in packages

Tags: java, package

I have a package called allocation in there,

I have classes such as:

- Result
- Command
- Slice
- Range

What would be best practise for this. The names such as Result sound very generic if you look at it without the package name appended to it.

Should I rename the Result class to AllocationResult? Or would this be redundant due to the package name being allocation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bad practice to have two classes of the same name in different packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6647510/bad-practice-to-have-two-classes-of-the-same-name-in-different-packages)

Comment: Do what **you** and **your** team find the most readable.

Comment: I would say, read the article that I linked then make your own logical as @JBNizet said

Comment: If you don’t expect your code to make use of other classes with the same base names, it is perfectly acceptable.